# Geographic coordinates c#

Tags: c#, geolocation, geography

How can I get the geographic coordinates of a place just by entering the addresses in input? on c #
I searched the internet but could not find information for c #

Comment: elaborate your question

Comment: Check out this library: https://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an API such as Googles Geocoding API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

But beware, the licence says the results must be displayed on a map!

If that's a problem, I'd look at the others in Mathew Watson's link: http://github.com/chadly/Geocoding.net